# Add "more results..." text to ui bootstrap typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I know its possible to set up your own template for each row in ui bootstrap typeahead. But I cannot find any way to add a "more results..." text at the end if the available options are more then for example 5. When there are five or less options the text shouldn't be visible.

Is it possible or do I have to check for another lib?

Answer (score 0):

I too had a problem when i was using Bootstrap Tagsinput and Typehead.js. And i modified in Bootstrap Tagsinput JS file in the line 41.

`this.placeholderText = element.hasAttribute('placeholder') ? this.$element.attr('placeholder') : "more results...";`